# Java8 Lambda: concat list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to concat list of a stream and process it.

```
class A {
    public List<B> bList;
}
List<A> aList;
aList.stream().map(a -> a.bList)....
```

Here i get several list of b.

But, I would like to collect all my b in only one list. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's what flatMap is for :

```
List<B> bList = aList.stream()
                     .flatMap(a -> a.bList.stream())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```